# lxc create unprivileged containers

Tags: virtual-machine, fedora, lxc

I've installed lxc for create containers and I've done the commands for create unprivileged containers but I've this errors when I do:

```
[andrea@andrea lxc]$ lxc-create -t download -n prova0
lxc-create: conf.c: chown_mapped_root: 3406 No mapping for container root
lxc-create: lxccontainer.c: do_bdev_create: 943 Error chowning /home/andrea/.local/share/lxc/prova0/rootfs to container root
lxc-create: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4444 Your system is not configured with subuids
lxc-create: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_create: 1408 Error creating backing store type (none) for prova0
lxc-create: lxc_create.c: main: 274 Error creating container prova0
```

Comment: Try this fantastic manual https://www.stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/

Answer (score 4):

```
lxc-create: ... Your system is not configured with subuids
```

As per the above error message, it sounds like you're trying to create an unprivileged container without subuids configured. These steps are for Ubuntu 14.04, but I suspect they will work on Fedora as well.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/lxc
$ echo "lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536" > ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
$ echo "lxc.id_map = g 0 100000 65536" >> ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
$ echo "lxc.network.type = veth" >> ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
$ echo "lxc.network.link = lxcbr0" >> ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
$ echo "$USER veth lxcbr0 2" | sudo tee -a /etc/lxc/lxc-usernet
```

Once these are configured, you should be able to create an ubuntu container, as follows:

```
$ lxc-create -t download -n u1 -- -d ubuntu -r trusty -a amd64
```

*Taken from the Ubuntu Server LXC guide:*
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-unpriv