# How do I update my Docker container so that it's unprivileged?

Tags: docker, security, dockerfile, containers, docker-container

### Problem

I have a frontend app that deploys in the Docker container `nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine-slim`. The pipeline is currently failing the stage that checks for security vulnerabilities via AquaScan.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine-slim
USER root
RUN apk update && apk upgrade --no-cache
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --chown=nginx ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
USER nginx
COPY build .
```

### Things I've tried

- Due to an issue with AquaScan, upgrading the vulnerable packages with `RUN apk update && apk upgrade --no-cache` does not pass the scan.
- Changing to a privileged container fails the deployment
- [lxc create unprivileged containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520980/lxc-create-unprivileged-containers) is a related post that doesn't work in my situation.

If I could update a different container to be unprivileged, then I could both pass AquaScan and deploy my app.

**How do I update my Docker container so that it's unprivileged?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I updated the `Dockerfile` like so:

```
# nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine-slim has container vulnerabilities that do not pass AquaScan, even after updating. 3/21/2023.
FROM nginx:alpine-slim
# implement changes required to run NGINX as an unprivileged user
RUN sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
  && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  # nginx user must own the cache and etc directory to write cache and tweak the nginx config    && chown -R $UID:0 /var/cache/nginx \
  && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx \
  && chown -R $UID:0 /etc/nginx \
  && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx
COPY --chown=nginx:nginx ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
USER nginx
EXPOSE 8080
COPY build .
```

Now my frontend app deploys in a container *and* passes AquaScan.

Comment: @PaulH I'll add the original file to my question...